# Select a value from dropdown list with the ID and display the ID selected in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is that I can only select the first index, but I want to select all values in  the dropdown list. I tried multiple combinations of selectedvalue or selectedindexchanged, but it still not working.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true"%>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="text/css" href="style1.css"/>
  <script language="c#" runat="server">
      string str = "Data Source=.;uid=sa;pwd=123;database=InventoryRouting";
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
              string com = "Select * from Plant";
              SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              adpt.Fill(dt);
              drop.DataSource = dt;
              drop.DataBind();
              drop.DataTextField = "PlantID";
              drop.DataValueField = "PlantID";
              drop.DataBind();
          }
          protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Plant where PlantID = '"+     drop.SelectedValue +"'", con);
              SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              Adpt.Fill(dt);
              grid.DataSource = dt;
              grid.DataBind();
          }
      </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1 style="background-color:red; width:500px;height:50px;">Plant     Information</h1><hr>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="right">
        Choose Plant ID to View Information<asp:DropDownList ID="drop" runat="server"     Width="100px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Button1_Click1">    </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <!--<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="View"     OnClick="Button1_Click1" Style="height: 26px" />-->
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999"
            BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center"     />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
        </center>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I select all ID from my dropdown list? Please help me

Comment: In a DropdownList you can only select one value at a time.

Comment: Ohhh, yes that OK, but even I select the other value from the starter of my run code, it still not work. for example: I select index 2 from my database, but it not show. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check Page.IsPostBack property before data binding. when you click button, page will postback and if you not put that condition new data will be loaded again. you will lost selection

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack){ // add this line 
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        string com = "Select * from Plant";
        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adpt.Fill(dt);
        drop.DataSource = dt;
        drop.DataBind();
        drop.DataTextField = "PlantID";
        drop.DataValueField = "PlantID";
        drop.DataBind();
    }
}
```